# Unity Subway surfers collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I been working on a game like subway surfers and I have been stuck with this problem for a while, I been trying to make a collision like subway surfers were if the player slides to the left and there is a train there, it will slow it down for a second and then make it go back to its normal speed. I have been watching this video that explains exactly on what I want to do(Video Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcygVd2XpD4)the problem is that the tutorial has some stuff that I did not put in my game, like they made the player switch lanes using the wasd keys and wrote a different code and I wrote a different code for that, the stuff that I did differently made the whole code not work. I been searching for a different way on how to do this but I can not find any tutorials that get the exact thing I want except that one.

```
This is my player swipe code:https://pastebin.com/d34G2ZU3
```

the part on my Collison code that makes my whole code not work is when I start adding the animation. Im not sure what exactly is stopping my code from working but I know that after I add the animation code nothing works, I get no errors and nothing really happens. I used stumbtolerance, stopallstate, and stumbletime to make it so my player can stumble but when I started adding the script from the tutorial were some parts that I did not have in my swipe code that he had and he referenced it in his collision code.Im trying to make a code that checks if the player switchs lanes and if there is something there, if there is then to make the player go back to its original spot and get slown down for a bit, if he collides with the thing again he dies.

my collision code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerCollisionCode : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public enum HitX { Left, Mid, Right, None }
    public enum HitY { Up, Mid, Down, Low, None }
    public enum HitZ { Forawd, Mid, Backward, None }
 
    public HitX hitX = HitX.None;
    public HitY hitY = HitY.None;
    public HitZ hitZ = HitZ.None;
    public bool EnemyCollide = false;
    public PlayerMovement pm;
    public Animator animator;
    public BoxCollider boxcollider;
    public bool StopAllState = false;
    public float stumbtolerance = 10f;
    public float stumbletime;
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        stumbletime = stumbtolerance;
        boxcollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
 
        if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime >= 1)
            StopAllState = false;
        stumbletime = Mathf.MoveTowards(stumbletime, stumbtolerance, Time.deltaTime);
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
 
    public HitX GetHitX(Collider other)
    {
        Bounds char_bounds = boxcollider.bounds;
        Bounds col_bounds = other.bounds;
        float min_x = Mathf.Max(col_bounds.min.x, char_bounds.min.x);
        float max_x = Mathf.Min(col_bounds.max.x, char_bounds.max.x);
        float average = (min_x + max_x) / 2f - col_bounds.min.x;
        HitX hit;
        if (average > col_bounds.size.x - 0.335)
            hit = HitX.Right;
        else if (average < 0.33f)
            hit = HitX.Left;
        else
            hit = HitX.Mid;
        return hit;
 
 
 
 
    }
 
    public HitY GetHitY(Collider other)
    {
        Bounds char_bounds = boxcollider.bounds;
        Bounds col_bounds = other.bounds;
        float min_y = Mathf.Max(col_bounds.min.y, char_bounds.min.y);
        float max_y = Mathf.Min(col_bounds.max.y, char_bounds.max.y);
        float average = ((min_y + max_y) / 2f - char_bounds.min.y) / char_bounds.size.y;
        HitY hit;
        if (average < 0.17f)
            hit = HitY.Low;
        else if (average < 0.335)
            hit = HitY.Down;
        else if (average < 0.33f)
            hit = HitY.Mid;
        else
            hit = HitY.Up;
        return hit;
 
 
 
 
    }
 
 
    public HitZ GetHitZ(Collider other)
    {
        Bounds char_bounds = boxcollider.bounds;
        Bounds col_bounds = other.bounds;
        float min_z = Mathf.Max(col_bounds.min.z, char_bounds.min.z);
        float max_z = Mathf.Min(col_bounds.max.z, char_bounds.max.z);
        float average = ((min_z + max_z) / 2f - char_bounds.min.z) / char_bounds.size.z;
        HitZ hit;
        if (average < 0.335)
            hit = HitZ.Backward;
        else if (average < 0.66f)
            hit = HitZ.Mid;
        else
            hit = HitZ.Forawd;
        return hit;
 
 
 
 
    }
 
    public void OnCharacterCollideHit(Collider other)
    {
        hitX = GetHitX(other);
        hitY = GetHitY(other);
        hitZ = GetHitZ(other);
        if (hitZ == HitZ.Forawd && hitX == HitX.Mid)
        {
            if (hitY == HitY.Low)
            {
                PlayAnimation("360Flip");
                ResetCollision();
            }
            else if (hitY == HitY.Down)
            {
                Stumble("360Flip");
            }
            else if (hitY == HitY.Mid)
            {
                if (other.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    ResetCollision();
                    StartCoroutine(DeathPlayer("CrushDeath"));
                }
                else if (other.tag != "Ramp")
                    Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                ResetCollision();
            }
            else if (hitY == HitY.Up)
            {
                Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                ResetCollision();
            }
        }
        else if (hitZ == HitZ.Mid)
        {
            if (hitX == HitX.Right)
            {
                Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                ResetCollision();
            }
            else if (hitX == HitX.Left)
            {
                }
        else if (hitZ == HitZ.Mid)
        {
            if (hitX == HitX.Right)
            {
                    Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                    ResetCollision();
            }
            else if (hitX == HitX.Left)
            {
                    Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                    ResetCollision();
 
            }
 
 
        }else{
 
                if (hitX == HitX.Right)
                {
                    Debug.Log("StubleCorneright");
                    ResetCollision();
                }
                else if (hitX == HitX.Left)
                {
                    Debug.Log("StubleCornerRight");
                    ResetCollision();
 
                }
 
 
            }
 
        }
    }
    private void ResetCollision()
    {
        print(hitX.ToString() + hitY.ToString() + hitZ.ToString());
        hitX = HitX.None;
        hitY = HitY.None;
        hitZ = HitZ.None;
 
 
    }
 
    public void PlayAnimation(string anim)
    {
        if (StopAllState) return;
        animator.Play(anim);
    }
 
 
    public void Stumble(string anim)
    {
        animator.ForceStateNormalizedTime(0.0f);
        StopAllState = true;
        animator.Play(anim);
        if (stumbletime < stumbtolerance / 2f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DeathPlayer("CrushDeath"));
            return;
        }
        stumbletime -= 6f;
        ResetCollision();
 
    }
 
    public IEnumerator DeathPlayer(string anim)
    {
        StopAllState = true;
        animator.Play(anim);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question and explain in more detail what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I looked at you're code for a bit and found an easy way to track how to collide with the sides, all you have to do it add another variable to check if youre finger swipes left or right, I called it `public bool LeftRight = 0` then in the part you tell it to swipe left make leftRight = 1 and for Right make it  = 2, After you done all that add this script

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && LeftRight == 2f)
        {
            stopTouch = true;
            targetLine--;
            canitmove = false;
            movec.x = -4;
            LeftRight = 1;
            Debug.Log("Lefts");
            line = 2;

        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && LeftRight == 1f)
        {
            stopTouch = true;
            targetLine++;
            canitmove = false;
            movec.x = 4;
            LeftRight = 2;
            Debug.Log("Right");
            line = 0;

        }
    }
```

checks if it collides with the Enemy and witch way it swiped. With this you can add on to my code and add whatever animation you want.

Comment: So when `LeftRight == 2` you want to execute both code blocks? Doesn't sound quite right ;) Also how exactly did you manage to compare a **bool** value `LeftRight` to a **float** `2f` and `1f` ?! ^^ This code shouldn't even compile